# C# WCF return request to self hosting server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am running WCF self hosting server. Connection is coming fine and I can process them.
But now for long connections we decided to break a connection, process request and send results back to self hosting server on client side.

How do I know which client should I send a request back? DO I need remember every client address? How do I know their address, should they provide back address as input parameter? Or maybe there are much easier, correct and elegant way to solve this common issue?

Comment: Why are you breaking the connection? I attempted something like this to avoid the clients from hanging... but then I realized I could just make the client calls async, and no need to cut off the connection.

Comment: Sounds like you could do with a callback contract. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17704/WCF-Duplex-Operations-and-UI-Threads

Comment: In disconnected or multi-connection applications, you should send connection string with every request (plus an encryption will keep your data secure)

Answer (score 1):

As [cillierscharl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498811/c-sharp-wcf-return-request-to-self-hosting-server/9508492#comment12026737_9498811) already said, you could use callback contracts.

Links to give you a quick start:

- [WCF Essentials - What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)
- [WCF Callbacks – A quick introduction](https://web.archive.org/web/20120305171904/https://dotnetthoughts.net/2011/06/24/wcf-callbacks-%E2%80%93-a-quick-introduction/)
- [Simple Example from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044174/what-steps-do-i-need-to-take-to-use-wcf-callbacks)
- [Chat Example](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/wcf/b5ada8df-58c5-492f-b368-457b3a4f137c/notify-client-applications-using-wcf-callbacks.aspx)
- [WCF Duplex Reentrant Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34460/WCF-Duplex-Reentrant-Services)
- [Best (beginners) article about WCF Callbacks](https://web.archive.org/web/20120204172328/http://codeidol.com/)
- [Stack Overflow: keeping a wcf callback channel open indefinitely / reconnecting from client if it faults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405930/keeping-a-wcf-callback-channel-open-indefinitely-reconnecting-from-client-if-i)
- [Synchronization Contexts in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx)

Advanced Stuff and things you should worry about:

- Detecting Client disconnection
- Reestablish Connection Management
- Concurrency Mode and Instancing (Threading..) / Synchronization Contexts